# Is it possible to de-duplicate if statements and their body in Rust, perhaps by using macros?

Tags: macros, rust

Say we have a large block:

```
mod module {
    pub const fiz: u32 = (1 << 0);
    // etc...
}

flag = {
    if      (var & module::fiz) != 0 { module::fiz }
    else if (var & module::foo) != 0 { module::foo }
    else if (var & module::bar) != 0 { module::bar }
    else if (var & module::baz) != 0 { module::baz }
    // .. there could be many more similar checks
};
```

With simply replacement macro its possible to do:

```
#define TEST(f) ((var) & (f)) != 0 { f }
```

Allowing:

```
flag = {
    if      TEST(module::fiz)
    else if TEST(module::foo)
    else if TEST(module::bar)
    else if TEST(module::baz)
}
```

It seems Rust doesn't allow a macro to declare part of an `if` statement.

I managed to avoid repetition using assignment, but its quite ugly.

```
flag = {
    let f;
    if      (var & {f = module::fiz; f }) != 0 { f }
    else if (var & {f = module::foo; f }) != 0 { f }
    else if (var & {f = module::bar; f }) != 0 { f }
    else if (var & {f = module::baz; f }) != 0 { f }
};
```

Does Rust provide some convenient/elegant way to allow repetition in this case?

I don't think flag checking is the important part of this question, the issue is that you may want to repeat content in the check again in the body of an if statement, e.g.:

```
if      (foo && OTHER_EXPRESSION) { do(); something_with(OTHER_EXPRESSION) }
else if (foo && SOME_EXPRESSION)  { do(); something_with(SOME_EXPRESSION)  }
```

Comment: Could you please post a complete code example (which compiles). I suppose `module::*` are supposed to be some kind of integral types... but I'd rather make sure that I have everything right.

Comment: @antoyo corrected

Comment: Does it matter if `OTHER_EXPRESSION` is evaluated only once (and its result cached), or if it's evaluated when it should not be needed?

Comment: @ideasman42 you have been asking a lot of questions lately, which is fine. However, I sincerely would have hoped that you have learned **how to ask a good question** by now. A great majority of your questions have had a comment asking you to improve in some fashion or another. At this point, those should be a rare occurrence. *Please* take that feedback and apply it to all questions going forward. And as a personal appeal, **please** learn how to use the Latin *e.g.* properly, it's the most annoying edit I have to make you every one of your questions.

Comment: @ideasman42 To continue in the same vein as Shepmaster, could you pleasse accept one answer on the many questions you asked? Or if none of them answers you question, please tell why it does not and possibly edit your questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I think you have an X/Y problem here, so I am going to solve this *without* using `if`/`else`.

What you seem to be doing is checking for the presence of a bit pattern, and prioritise the order in which said patterns are checked for (unclear if it matters, but let's assume it does).

So, let's do this the functional way:

```
let constants = [fiz, foo, bar, baz];

let flag = constants.iter().filter(|v| var & *v == **v).next();
```

And it [just works](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=249b503ce5f4fa98928810cb78f00656&version=stable&backtrace=0), no macro or repetitive stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I simplified the question from my own code to make it easier to follow, the body of each if statement is more then just a single flag expression. *(am still interested if this can be done by de-duplicating the if check and its body).*

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use macros, you can write it like this:

```
mod module {
    pub const fiz: u32 = (1 << 0);
    pub const foo: u32 = (1 << 1);
    pub const bar: u32 = (1 << 2);
    pub const baz: u32 = (1 << 3);
}

macro_rules! check_bits {
    ([$($Constant:expr),*]) => {
        |var: u32| {
            $(if ($Constant & var) != 0 {
                return $Constant;
            })*
                return 0;
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let var = 5;
    let checker = check_bits!([module::bar, module::fiz, module::foo, module::baz]);
    assert_eq!(checker(var), module::bar);
    println!("All OK");
}
```